# How do I make separate characters in a string random fonts?

Tags: javascript, html, string, loops

I'm currently trying to write a block of Javascript in my webpage that takes text from a text area and converts each individual character in the string into a random font.

This is my current attempt (which doesn't work):

```
<body>
    <div class="container main-form">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="textinput">Input your text below</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="textinput" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right" id="submit">Generate</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container output">
      <script>
        var input = "";
        var ouput = "";
        var inputarr = [];
        // Array of fonts for span
        var fontarr = ["font-family: MaxHand1, sans-serif", "font-family: MaxHand2, sans-serif", "font-family: MaxHand3, sans-serif"];
        if document.getElementById('submit').clicked == true { // If button is clicked
          input = document.getElementById('textinput'); // Set 'input' string to what was in the text area
          inputarr = input.split(""); // Create an array of letters from input
          for (i = 0; i < inputarr.length; i++) {
            fontchange = fontarr[Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)]; // Choose a random font
            output = (output + "<span style=\"" + fontchange + "\">" + inputarr[i] + "</span>"); // Add <span style="[fontchange]">inputarr[i]</span> to output string
          }
          document.getElementById(textoutput) = output; // Output string to line 45
        }
      </script>
      <p id="textoutput"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

When I click submit, though, nothing appears on screen. I'm not sure if it's just because the string isn't being changed, or if it's just not updating the textoutput p tags.

Comment: `document.getElementById(textoutput) = output` is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couples of syntax errors in your code. `document.getElementById('submit').clicked == true` and `document.getElementById(textoutput) = output` and `input = document.getElementById('textinput')` <--- this will not return string(it will return whole tag). Try below code(I fixed error)

those changes from the previous answer plus you need to modify your Math.random call so you get 0,1,2 --> I did this using the % (mod) operator

```js
var fontarr = ["font-family: courier new, sans-serif", 
               "font-family: comic sans, sans-serif", 
               "font-family: arial black, sans-serif"];
function change(){ 
    var input = "";
    var output = "";
    
    input = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        fontchange = fontarr[Math.floor(((Math.random() * 3) + 1)%3)];
        output += "<span style=\"" + fontchange + "\">" + input[i] + "</span>";
        
    }
    //console.log(output);
    document.getElementById("textoutput").innerHTML = output;      
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container main-form">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="textinput">Input your text below</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="textinput" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right" id="submit" onclick="change()">Generate</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container output">
      <script>
        
      </script>
      <p id="textoutput"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: When I run it, the text is displayed (thanks so much!) but only some of the characters are changed. Could this be an issue with only one of the fonts working in fontarr?

Comment: @MaxWalters that's possible, but if you click _generate_ mutiple time you can see character changes

Comment: check your random call, it needs to be modified to return index of 0,1,2

Comment: @MaxWalters modified the answer(change the fonts) now you can see a clear difference.(and if you want to see whether font assign are different or not just uncomment _console.log(output)_)

Comment: @DCR I can't believe I missed that, one of those slips of the mind lol
& yajiv, I just changed the 3 in Math.random to a 2, but thank you so much for your help!